# List.js --- when I search by city or state on a table for ["New York, NY", "Ft Lauderdale, FL", "Miami, FL", " Quincy, MA", "Englewood, CO"]

Tags: javascript, list.js

I used list.js on this page https://comcastspotlight.com/jobs to search job by location.

When I search by City name it works.
However can't get an exact result when I search by state.

Example, PA ( try to search for PA, CA, or others state)

```
Role    Location(s) Job Type
CRM/ Order Management Platform Director Wayne, PA
Englewood, CO, New York, NY Full Time
Ad Sales Account Executive  Sparta, NJ
Full Time
Ad Sales Account Executive  West Palm Beach, FL
Full Time
Ad Sales Account Executive  West Palm Beach, FL
Full Time
Ad Sales Account Executive  West Palm Beach, FL
Full Time
Associate Account Executive West Conshohocken, PA
Full Time
Associate Account Executive Pittsburgh, PA
Full Time
Sr. Manager, Human Resources - Spotlight Operations Wayne, PA
Full Time
Engineer 4, Software Dev & Engineering  Wayne, PA
Full Time
Sr. Mgr Facilities -Safety, Security, Fleet, Projects   Wayne, PA
Englewood, CO, Alpharetta, GA, Bingham Farms, MI    Full Time
```

Here is the code:

```
<script>
    var options = {
        valueNames: [ 'city-state' ]
    };

    var userList = new List('users', options);
    userList.on('updated', function(list) {
        if (list.matchingItems.length > 0) {

            $('.notFirst20').show();
            console.log('seth there are ' + list.matchingItems.length + ' matching items! ');
            $('.no-result').hide()
        } else {
            $('.no-result').show()
        }
        if ($('.search').val().length < 2){
            console.log('the value is now less than 2 ');
            if($('.notFirst20').is(':visible')){
                console.log('we know its visible so lets toggle it off');
                $('.notFirst20').hide();
                //$('.notFirst20').toggle();
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks

---> I tried below rules:

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var options = "Wayne, PA";
        var res = options.slice(-2); !– get result–>
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    }
</script>


<br><hr /><br>

<button onclick="myFunction1()">Try it 2</button>

<p id="demo1"></p>

<script>
    function myFunction1() {
        var options = ["New York, NY", "Ft Lauderdale, FL", "Miami, FL", " Quincy, MA", "Englewood, CO"];
        var state = options.slice(-2); !– no result–>
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = state;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: for `Try it 2`, it will return last two elements of the array. why said no result?

Comment: no result, when I use it on list.js. I've 70+ items. options.slice(-2) will show last items and search. Got it

Comment: you mean `var state = options.slice(-2)` return no result?

Comment: will get last 2 items: Quincy, MA,Englewood, CO. but if you want to search NY on ["New York, NY", "Ft Lauderdale, FL", "Miami, FL", " Quincy, MA", "Englewood, CO"], you'll not get result

Comment: does this one works as you expected `console.log(options.filter(function(item){return item.slice(-2) == 'NY'}))`?

Comment: Those are just example. 
Here is the js code I use from http://listjs.com/examples/table/

var options = {
            valueNames: [ 'city-state' ]
        };

        var userList = new List('users', options);

My question was when I search by state on https://comcastspotlight.com/jobs, I want to get only that state result.